# Get name of all Office 365 groups

Tags: powershell, office365, usergroups

I am attempting to write my first PS script and would like to check if a Name of an Office 365 group already exists in the system. So I set the vars and want to check if GN matches a group name already in the system, how can I access all the names from the Get-UnifiedGroup var?

```
$Groupname = "test group"
$Alias = "testing"
$AccessType = "Public"
$GN = Get-UnifiedGroup

 #Check if Group Exists already
            if ($GN = $Groupname)  
            {  
                write-Host "Group $GroupName exists Already!" -ForegroundColor Red 
            }  
            else  

New-UnifiedGroup –DisplayName "$Groupname" -Alias ="$Alias" -AccessType = "$AccessType"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the name property of the variable with ."property"

```
if ($GN.Name -contains $Groupname)
```

the `-contains` operator checks if an array contains your `$groupname` or you could do it the other way around:

```
if ($GroupName -in $GN.Name)
```

Also, for big chunks of data, you are probably better off with `.Contains()` array method (as it is usually faster), so like this:

```
if (($GN.Name).Contains($GroupName))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I am still learning and this really helped